# How to split HTML into lines and preserve HTML structure in TypeScript?

Tags: html, css, parsing

I am struggling with this since a long time, so if anyone could help me out, I would be really grateful. I want to split HTML into lines (at the \n character), but also preserve every textnode, and every existing node. This problematic in the below case.

- example HTML of the below code block:
  [image]

  ```
  <code class="language-diff is-loaded"><span class="token coord">@@ -1 +1,2 @@</span>
  <span class="token deleted-sign deleted"><span class="token prefix deleted">-</span> 
  <span class="token line">print('hello world')
  </span></span><span class="token inserted-sign inserted"><span class="token prefix 
  inserted">+</span><span class="token line">for i in range(10):
  </span><span class="token prefix inserted">+</span><span class="token line">    
  print('hello world')
  </span></span></code>
  ```

[image]

Here, the problem is that there is a span element with the class "token inserted-sign inserted" which has child span elements, and they also contains a new line. So after splitting it I get:

```
line 1: <span class="token coord">@@ -1 +1,2 @@</span>
line 2: <span class="token deleted-sign deleted"><span class="token prefix deleted">- 
</span><span class="token line">print('hello world')</span></span>
line 3: <span class="token inserted-sign inserted"><span class="token prefix inserted">+ 
</span><span class="token line">for i in range(10):</span></span>
line 4: <span class="token prefix inserted">+</span><span class="token line">    
print('hello world')</span>
```

Line 4 is incorrect since it "lost it's parent element, and the classes associated to its parent". Correct would be this:

```
<span class="token inserted-sign inserted"><span class="token prefix inserted">+</span> 
<span class="token line">    print('hello world')</span></span>
```

I need to split the HTML into line so I can manipulate it as I want, but I can't figure out how to do that correctly. I hope it is clear what I want.

Comment: There are no "lines" in the HTML you've shown: it's just a series of `span` elements. The rendering logic which determines where the visual line breaks occur is encoded into CSS class names. You'll need to consult the associated style sheet to determine how to parse that information.

Comment: @jsejcksn: sorry, maybe I used the wrong phrase. I know there are no lines, I meant that I want all the elements which one code line consists of.

Comment: Details in that sample suggest that it was likely generated by [Prism.js](https://prismjs.com/). Reading the documentation will probably be helpful.

Comment: @jsejcksn yes it was generated with prism.js, but I do not generate it. This is part of an Obsidian plugin, so when I have access to it, the classes are already associated to the text, and structure already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) which is available in every decently modern browser.

Below is a demo that uses DOMParser to dissect your html into nodes, childNodes, nodeType, nodeName, node attributes (each with name and value) and prints it all to the `console`.

What isn't shown below is that the **doc** object is actually "**live**": you can alter its nodes, add/remove nodes, move them around etc, and you can ask it what HTML (text) it "contains" after every change.

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();

const html = `<code class="language-diff is-loaded"><span class="token coord">@@ -1 +1,2 @@</span>
<span class="token deleted-sign deleted"><span class="token prefix deleted">-</span> 
<span class="token line">print('hello world')
</span></span><span class="token inserted-sign inserted"><span class="token prefix 
inserted">+</span><span class="token line">for i in range(10):
</span><span class="token prefix inserted">+</span><span class="token line">    
print('hello world')
</span></span></code>`;

const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

function showElement(node, indent = 0) {
  const prefix = " ".repeat(indent);
  const nodeType = "nodeType = " + node.nodeType;
  const textContent = node.nodeType === 3 ? ", textContent = '" + node.textContent + "'" : "";
  const attributes = node.attributes?.length > 0 ? ", " + Array.from(node.attributes).map(attr => attr.nodeName + "='" + attr.nodeValue + "'").join(" ") : "";
  console.log(prefix + node.nodeName + ": " + nodeType + textContent + attributes + ".");
  if (node.childNodes?.length > 0)
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
      showElement(node.childNodes[i], indent + 2);
}

showElement(doc.body);

console.log("-".repeat(30));
console.log("innerHTML:");
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

If you look beyond my not-so-clean sample code, you'll see that DOMParser can do lots of what you need, and maybe even everything you need.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I was approaching the whole problem wrong. I will definitely look into this.